# SQL multiple table conditional retrieving statement

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve data from an sqlite table conditional on another sqlite table within the same database. The formats are the following:

```
master table
--------------------------------------------------
| id         | TypeA    | TypeB      | ...     
--------------------------------------------------
| 2020/01/01 | ID_0-0   |ID_0-1      | ...
--------------------------------------------------
```

```
child table

--------------------------------------------------
| id         | Attr1    | Attr2      | ...     
--------------------------------------------------
| ID_0-0     | 112.04   |-3.45       | ...
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write an sqlite3 query that takes:

- A date D present in master.id
- A list of types present in master's columns
- A list of attributes present in child's columns

and returns a dataframe with rows the types and columns the attributes. Of course, I could just read the tables into pandas and do the work there, but I think it would be more computationally intensive and I want to learn more SQL syntax!

**UPDATE**
**So far I've tried:**

```
"""SELECT *
   FROM child 
   WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT *
        FROM master
        WHERE master.TypeX  = Type_input
        WHERE master.dateX  = date_input)"""
```

and then concatenate the strings over all required TypeX and dateX and execute with:

```
cur.executescripts(script)
```

Comment: How many `TypeX` columns do you have? You probably should normalize the schema so those are a single column in multiple rows.

Comment: Anyway, just join the tables and then use `WHERE` clauses to filter based on the list of types and attributes.

Comment: The join condition would be something like `ON child.id IN (master.TypeA, master.TypeB, ...)`.

Comment: Hello Barmar. Thanks for replying to my question. I have about 5000 TypeX columns and 10,000,000 rows for dates so master is a=10,000,000*5000. How would you normalise this schema? Would you suppress the master table and create an id in child of pairs of (TypeX,dateX)?

Comment: You should have a table with columns `id`, `typename`, `typevalue`. However, I admit that it will be 50% bigger since the `id` column has to be repeated in every row. But it will make queries far easy, since you won't have to enumerate all the TypeX columns when you need to search them all.